# How to allow Azure CDN (Standard Microsoft) to allow "set-cookie" for "ASP.NET_SessionId"?

Tags: cookies, setcookie, azure-cdn

My site uses ASP.NET_SessionId cookies. This is standard ASP.NET header used for session management. 
CDN itself removes some headers from the response: in this case, the browser is not receiving "set-cookie" header for "ASP.NET_SessionId", despite the fact, it was sent by the web site (see screenshots below).

The home page is dynamic and is not intended to be cached. Also, page sets "no-cache" header.

This happens **only** with Azure CDN with **Standard Microsoft** profile.

**Could you please provide any ideas on how to allow set-cookie to pass-through the CDN?**

---

Original response headers:

Original Headers (two)

[image: Original Headers (two)]

As you can see there are two "Set-Cookie" headers.

---

CDN-ified response headers:

Headers with CDN (one)

[image: Headers with CDN (one)]

As you can see only one "Set-Cookie" header left, "ASP.NET_SessionId" is removed by CDN (some security rule?).

---

I cannot find any documentation on how to allow all headers to pass-through.

Thank you!

Comment: Submitted ticket to Microsoft support. I will update that page once there is any clarity.

Comment: Microsoft confirmed that issue (already know about it) and they are working on resolving it. No ETA or workaround provided.

Comment: Microsoft has provided workaround: use CDN caching rules and set the configuration to "bypass" by default. Enable caching for specific subpaths and extensions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ASP.NET session ID could not be cached as CDN could not cache such resources:

> Dynamic resources that change frequently or are unique to an
>   individual user cannot be cached.

You can get more details about [how CDN caching works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works).

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is that it removes that header from the response, so that browser doesn't get it. I don't want and don't need to cache it.

Comment: It should not intervene and modify a response by deleting some cookies it doesn't like breaking Microsoft session management in ASP.NET.